# show subscription on dbname; Return to the system view, with column attribute names in capital letters

Tags: cnosdb

#### Describe the bug

show subscription on dbname; Return to the system view, with column attribute names in capital letters

#### To Reproduce

```
db001 ❯ show subscription on db001;
+--------------+----------------+------+
| SUBSCRIPTION | DESTINATIONS   | MODE |
+--------------+----------------+------+
| sub001       | 127.0.0.1:8912 | ALL  |
+--------------+----------------+------+
Query took 0.001 seconds.
```

version:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 842fc0e37a28327f14805f7ebe7ca1a85fca721c